# phpmyadmin Error #2003 the server is not responding

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

after battling my way through every error message to try and get phpmyadmin running I am finally stumped by the last message.  #2003 - The server is not responding.  I think I know that its a problem between phpmyadmin and my installation of MySQL but I just cant find the hook.
I have already set the socket in the config.inc.php.  I don't care if it works remotely i just need it to run locally for now.  MySQL client connects just fine.  I can do stuff from the command line so I know MySQL is configured and running. running typical LAMP stack CentOS 7 and mariadb.  MySQL port is 3306
socket=/var/lib/MySQL/MySQL.sock (the stackoverflow web form keeps changing the case of MySQL so I am aware of the case sensitivity)
the main login page comes up fine but gives the 2003 error after typing in password.  I know the correct password and I am typing it in correctly.
any help appreciated.

Comment: See also the comments from: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19149900/2003-the-server-is-not-responding

Comment: I found this which at least got me up and running locally.  thanks http://www.tecmint.com/install-lamp-in-centos-7/  seems I couldn't follow the instructions exactly because for some reason I couldn't get to the rpmforge but epel release worked and allowed me to install.  folder names are different this time, seems everytime I do this its different than last time so no amount of note taking helps.